# Markup compatible notepad

Tags: text-editor, note-taking, plain-text, text-processing

I'm looking for a ***[notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note-taking)*** */ text-organizer*.
Maybe something *similar to* ***[KeepNote](http://keepnote.org/manual/#philosophy)***.

- It *must support* ***[markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)*** style formatting.
- If it supports *basic* ***[HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/309164)***, that's a bonus.
- *Preferably* ***[Linux](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html)***-compatible, but whatever.

Comment: Notepads you can find plenty (and I could name some for Linux, even recommend one that matches "markup, HTML, Linux, Notepad"). But could you please elaborate on the "organizer" part? Asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you mean by *markup style formatting*? *markup* is a generic term that encompasses any kinds of languages with inline annotations, not a concrete syntax.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper There is a Wikipedia article hyperlink embedded in the body of the question that explains it much better than i can.

Comment: @tjt263: There is, and it explains that *markup* is a generic term that encompasses any kinds of languages with inline annotations, not a concrete syntax. Which leads back to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Boostnote.
Boostnote is an Open source note-taking app for programmers.
It focuses on writing Markdown note and code snippet quickly, can organized in a better way.
You can sync data to multi-devices(Mac, Windows, Linux, Android and iOS) via Dropbox.

■ Download
https://boostnote.io

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/):

- Supports a variant of Markdown
- Can include links & images
- Stored as plain text, backup as zip
- Various search and organiser tools
- Cross Platform - Linux, OS-X & Windows, even portable.
- Free: Gratis & Open Source (GPL)
- Spell Check
- Export to plain text, HTML, Latex or PDF

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Laverna](https://laverna.cc/%20Laverna).  I don't know how well it covers your "organizer" requirements, but it:

- Supports Markdown
- Is cross-platform (Linux explicitly mentioned, also windows etc)
- Supports encryption
- Is (can be?) self-hosted and locally stored
- Free and open source ([on Github](https://github.com/Laverna/laverna/releases))

**NOTE** Although it works for me (better as a note taker than note organizer, however), I observe in this question [An open alternative for Evernote?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35392/an-open-alternative-for-evernote) that some people are having issues with Laverna when they attempt to use Dropbox for synchronization.

Comment: Sounds interesting, thanks. I'll check it out.